# Discord.js How to get description of reddit post

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, reddit

I have this code where it gets a random post from r/memes and it get's the post's title with an image attached to it(if there is one), I got this with a lot of help and I just want it to be able to read the post's description. I want to be able to read the text if there is some in the post if I want to use this on like news subreddits or something.

```js
if (msg.content == '-meme') {
 function loadMemes() {
  // Fetch JSON
  return (
   fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json?limit=800&?sort=hot&t=all')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    // Return the actual posts
    .then((json) => json.data.children)
  );
 }

 function postRandomMeme(message) {
  return loadMemes().then((posts) => {
   // Get a random post's title and URL
   const { title, url } = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)].data;
   // Create the embed
   const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
    title,
    image: { url },
    footer: { text: 'Subreddit : r/memes' },
   });
   // Send the embed
   return message.channel.send(embed);
  });
 }

 // Usage:
 postRandomMeme(msg);
 // Log all errors
 //.catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a github repository called `reddit-bot` which is open source and online. you can possibly get an idea from the code provided on there.

`https://github.com/lowJ/reddit-bot/blob/master/index.js`

I also found this npm package specifically made to get memes and also has an open source github repository.

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/@blad3mak3r/reddit-memes`